# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

Tags: javascript, jquery, cross-domain

I try to access the [ORCID API](http://support.orcid.org/knowledgebase/articles/116874-orcid-api-guide) through JavaScript. I use JSONPfor the cross domain call but get this error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

Bellow is the code I use:

```
<html >
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function()
    {
$.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url:'http://pub.orcid.org/0000-0002-5426-4031/orcid-bio',
        dataType: 'jsonp'
        }).done(function(res){alert("sucess")}).
          fail(function(res){alert("failed"); console.log(res)}).
          always(function(res){alert("complete")});
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The URL you use there doesn't return JSON, but XML.

Comment: JSONP has to be supported by the server. Telling jQuery to expect JSONP does not make automagically happen.

Comment: @ZeginisDimitris: The posted Javascript code seems incomlete (another line with `})` is missing). Have you posted the real code?

Comment: ORCID works with CORS, not JSONP

Answer (score 2):

According to [this page](http://support.orcid.org/knowledgebase/articles/132271-retreiving-data-with-the-public-api) the service will only return JSON if you explicitly request it via the appropriate `Accept` header.

```
Accept: application/orcid+json
```

This will tell the server to produce JSON output, it will *not* automatically enable JSONP, which doesn't seem to be supported by ORCID.

There's [a request to add JSONP on their support site](http://support.orcid.org/forums/175591-orcid-ideas-forum/suggestions/3312127-add-jsonp-to-supported-datatypes).

Comment: How to set the Accept: application/orcid+json
I use the 'accepts' 
 $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url:'http://pub.orcid.org/0000-0002-5426-4031/orcid-bio',
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        accepts:'application/orcid+json'
        }).done(function(res){alert("sucess")}).
          fail(function(res){alert("failed"); console.log(res)}).
          always(function(res){alert("complete")});
    });

but the request header is still like this
"Accept: */*"